# Inno Setup FileCopy using {app} variable as part of directory

Tags: inno-setup

How can i use variables in Inno Setup `FileCopy` command in the `[Code]` section?

```
`FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{app}\Backup\config.ini'),ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\config.ini'),False);`
```

This is what i am using but not seem to work... Im using this inside a Procedure... And calling this Procedure using `Afterinstall:` in `[Files]` section.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\dev\bin\config.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\bin\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Tasks: Steam; AfterInstall: RunOtherInstaller;


[Code]
procedure RunOtherInstaller;
    var 
    Path: String;
    ErrorCode: Integer;
    begin
      if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Valve\Steam', 'InstallPath', Path)) and (FileExists(Path + '\Steam.exe')) then 
      begin
        //ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('"' + Path + '\Steam.exe' + '"'), 'steam://','', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
        Exec(ExpandConstant(Path + '\Steam.exe'), 'steam://', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode)
      end
      else
      begin
        MsgBox('Steam not found', mbError, MB_OK);
        FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{app}\Backup\config.ini'),ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\config.ini'),False);
        end
    end;
```

Comment: Could you post some more code please? When do you call this function? Is it after `{app}` is set? For clear code you could call it `ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Backup\config.ini'`. But still you should first check if file exists and then perform the copy action.

Comment: The code is correct. What does "Does not seem to work" mean? What does it do? What does the function `FileCopy` function return? Does the target directory exist?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl "Does not seem to work" means the FileCopy is not copying the config.ini file from the backup folder to the production folder after check through registry that the Steam program is not installed. Files and directories exists.. They are installed in Files section...

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and put the details there where they can be seen, instead of burying them in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileCopy` function does not create directories. It just copies files from an existing directory to other existing directory.

What you try to do is to copy `config.ini` from `Backup` directory to `bin` directory.

I have changed the call for `steam://` with an example how to run Sang-Froid game (you can change it anyway you need) and then I have added few sample checks that are just an example. At the end there is your `FileCopy` function with additional check with message if copy action is not possible either due to Config.ini or destination directory missing.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "C:\dev\bin\config.ini"; DestDir: "{app}\bin\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Tasks: Steam; AfterInstall: RunOtherInstaller;


[Code]
procedure RunOtherInstaller;
    var 
    Path: String;
    ErrorCode: Integer;
    begin
      if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Valve\Steam', 'InstallPath', Path)) and (FileExists(Path + '\Steam.exe')) then 
      begin
        //proper call for Steam:// - this sample tries to run Sang-Froid - Tales of Werewolves
        ShellExec('', 'steam://rungameid/227220', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
        //your EXEC 
        //Exec(ExpandConstant(Path + '\Steam.exe'), 'steam://', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode)
      end
      else
      begin
        MsgBox('Steam not found', mbError, MB_OK);
        //just some checks
        MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{app}'), mbError, MB_OK);
         if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\bin') then 
           MsgBox('''bin'' directory Exists', mbError, MB_OK)
         else
           MsgBox('''bin'' directory does not Exist!', mbError, MB_OK);
         if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Backup') then 
           MsgBox('''Backup'' directory Exists', mbError, MB_OK)
         else
           MsgBox('''Backup'' directory does not Exist!', mbError, MB_OK);
        //end of checks
        //check if Source file exists, check if destination directory exists
         if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Backup\config.ini') and DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\bin') then begin
           FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Backup\config.ini',ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\bin\config.ini',False);
         end
         else begin
           MsgBox('Either ''Config.ini'' file or ''bin'' directory does not Exist!', mbError, MB_OK);
         end;
        end
    end;
```